# How to install CL-Opengl with SBCL?

Tags: opengl, installation, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

So I was just wondering how to install opengl for SBCL? I'm on a 64-bit Windows 8 notebook. 
I did use quicklisp and quickload but when I actually use it in a program I get an error like this:

```
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined functions:
;     DRAW-FRAME INIT-GL
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions
```

and this is my code:

```
(require 'cl-opengl)
(require 'cl-glu)
(require 'lispbuilder-sdl)

(defun main-loop ()
  (sdl:with-init ()
    (sdl:window 800 800
        :title-caption "OpenGL Test"
        :opengl t
        :opengl-attributes '((:sdl-gl-doublebuffer 1)
                             (:sdl-gl-depth-size 16)))
    (setf (sdl:frame-rate) 20)

    (init-gl)
    (draw-frame)
    (sdl:update-display)

    (sdl:with-events ()
      (:quit-event () t)
      (:video-expose-event ()
        (sdl:update-display))
      (:idle ()
        (draw-frame)
        (sdl:update-display)))))
```

Comment: No one can help you, if you not explaining what you doing and what you got. As I see, this is a style warning, not an error.

Comment: @coredump, while these messages are indeed warnings, undefined function in code is nothing good at all.

Comment: @Mark, Couldn't it be defined in another place and just not proclaimed as function in this compilation unit?

Comment: @coredump, I have included my code.

Comment: What are init-gl and draw-frame ? Are they part of cl-opengl or some other library ? If so, why don't they prefixed with a package name (gl: or sdl: etc.) ?

Comment: As @cybevnm said, you must prefix draw-frame and init-gl with package name, or include it in your namespace by calling use-package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look at [the page that your code seems to have come from.](http://blog.lowsnr.net/2013/04/14/using-opengl-with-common-lisp-and-macos-x/)

It appears that the compiler is not lying, and that `(init-gl)` and `(draw-frame)` are not defined.

From what I can tell, the author of the above page later included a definition of `(draw-frame)` that looks like this:

> `(defun draw-frame (rotx roty rotz)
>     (gl:matrix-mode :modelview)
>     (gl:push-matrix)
>     (gl:translate 0.5 0.5 0.5)
>     (gl:rotate rotx 1 0 0)
>     (gl:rotate roty 0 1 0)
>     (gl:rotate rotz 0 0 1)
>     (gl:translate -0.5 -0.5 -0.5)
>     (draw-figure +cube-vertices+ +cube-faces+)
>     (gl:pop-matrix))`

However, it looks like `(init-gl)` was later renamed to `(start)`, which begins like this:

> `(defun start ()
>     (let ((rotx 0)
>           (roty 0)
>           (rotz 0))`

The author describes `(init-gl)` as setting up "the viewing parameters, lighting, culling, modelview matrix etc", which looks to be exactly what his function `(start)` accomplishes.

Incidentally, [cybevnm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170050/cybevnm) was asking all the right questions, and answering those questions probably would have led you to a similar conclusion.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should install [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/). Then to load all the packages you only need to do `(ql:quickload '<system-name>)`. All three system's you are using are available through quicklisp and many more.